Trigonometric inequality
For odd and coprime positive integers $p$ and $q$, the following inequality holds:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{n=1}^{q} \frac{2}{\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})} \le pq(|p-q|+1)$$
Unfortunately, the problem has no solution at MSE.

Where does this inequality comes from?

Here

I will continue from the point where Christophe Leuridan's answer stopped. Denote our sum $S$, then
$$
S=2p\sum_{n=1}^q \frac{\sin(2\pi np/q)}{(1+\cos(2πnp/q))\sin(2\pi n/q)}.
$$
For $n=q$ this is undefined, but the limit of our summand is $p/2$. Hence $S=p^2+2pT$ with
$$
T=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1} \frac{\sin(2\pi np/q)}{(1+\cos(2\pi np/q))\sin(2\pi n/q)}.
$$
Next, assume that $p<q$ and $q-p=2h$. We want to prove $S\leq pq(2h+1)$. This is the same as $p^2+2pT\leq pq(2h+1)$, i.e. $T\leq h(q+1)$. Since $\sin(2u)=2\sin(u)\cos(u)$, $1+\cos(2u)=2\cos^2(u)$, we see that
$$
T=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1} \frac{\tan(\pi np/q)}{\sin(2\pi n/q)}.
$$
Next, $\tan(\pi np/q)=-\tan(2\pi hn/q)$. Let $\zeta_q=\exp(2\pi i/q)$. Then we get
$$
\frac{\tan(\pi np/q)}{\sin(2\pi n/q)}=-\frac{\zeta_q^{nh}-\zeta_q^{-nh}}{\zeta_q^n-\zeta_q^{-n}}\cdot\frac{2}{\zeta_q^{nh}+\zeta_q^{-nh}}.
$$
Expand the two fractions on the right-hand side into finite geometric series:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\zeta_q^{nh}-\zeta_q^{-nh}}{\zeta_q^n-\zeta_q^{-n}}
&=\zeta_q^{-n(h-1)}\sum_{a=0}^{h-1}\zeta_q^{2na},\\ 
\frac{2}{\zeta_q^{nh}+\zeta_q^{-nh}}
&=\zeta_q^{nh}\sum_{b=0}^{q-1}(-1)^b\zeta_q^{2bnh}.
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$
T=-\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}\zeta_q^{n}\sum_{\substack{0\leq a\leq h-1\\ 0\leq b\leq q-1}}(-1)^b\zeta_q^{2na+2bnh}.
$$
Switching the order of summation and using the fact that sum of $\zeta_q^{nk}$ over $1\leq n\leq q-1$ is $-1$ for $q\nmid k$ and $q-1$ for $q\mid k$, we see that
$$
T=-q\sum_{\substack{0\leq a\leq h-1\\0\leq b\leq q-1\\2a+2bh\equiv -1 \pmod q}}(-1)^b+h\sum_{0\leq b\leq q-1}(-1)^b.
$$
The second sum is equal to $1$ and the first one is at least $-h$, since $h$ and $q$ are coprime (hence for fixed $a$ there is a unique $b$). Therefore, $T\leq (-q)(-h)+h=q(h+1)$, as needed.
Added by GH from MO. The result of the above calculation can be expressed in the more symmetric form
$$\frac{1}{pq}\sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{n=1}^{q} \frac{2}{\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})}=1-2\sum_{\substack{0\leq a\leq h-1\\0\leq b\leq q-1\\pb\equiv 2a+1 \pmod q}}(-1)^b.$$

There is a short way to take out trigonometry and remain with the sum of $\pm 1$, similar (but not immediately equivalent, see later) to these appearing in the Christophe Leuridan and Alexander Kalmynin's solution:
\begin{align*}\sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{n=1}^{q} \frac{2}{\cos(\frac{2m\pi}{p})+\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{q})}
&=\sum_{x^q=y^p=1}\frac4{x+1/x+y+1/y}\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{x^q=y^p=1}\frac{4x}{(1+x/y)(1+xy)}\\[4pt] &=\sum_{x^q=y^p=1}\frac{x(1+(x/y)^{pq})(1+(xy)^{pq})}{(1+x/y)(1+xy)}\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{x^q=y^p=1}x\sum_{a=0}^{pq-1}(-1)^a(x/y)^a\sum_{b=0}^{pq-1}(-1)^b(xy)^b\\[4pt]
&=pq\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant a,b\leqslant pq-1\\q|1+a+b,\ p|b-a}}(-1)^{a+b},
\end{align*}
since the summation of a single monomial $x^A y^B$ over $\{x^q=y^p=1\}$ gives $pq$ when $q|A$ and $p|B$ and 0 otherwise.
Thus, an equivalent reformulation of the inequality is
$$
M:=\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant a,b\leqslant pq-1\\q|1+a+b,\ p|b-a}}(-1)^{a+b}\leqslant |p-q|+1.\tag{$\heartsuit$}
$$
I include the proof of $(\heartsuit)$, it is short and elementary but, as for me, not trivial. Without Sasha's answer I would think longer about this. We may assume (from the very beginning) that $q>p$. Call a pair $(a,b)\in \{0,1,\ldots,pq-1\}^2$ appropriate, if $q|1+a+b$ and $p|b-a$, and denote the set of appropriate pairs by $\Theta$.
We partition the sum over appropriate pairs in $(\heartsuit)$ onto three parts, over the sets $\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3$, where
\begin{align*}
\Omega_1&:=\{(a,b)\in \Theta:(q-p)/2\leqslant a\leqslant pq-1,(q+p)/2\leqslant b\leqslant pq-1\}\\
\Omega_2&:=\{(a,b)\in \Theta:0\leqslant a<(q-p)/2\}\\
\Omega_3&:=\{(a,b)\in \Theta:0\leqslant b<(q+p)/2\}.
\end{align*}
Note that the sets $\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$ and $\Omega_3$ are disjoint (for a pair of integers $(a,b)$ enjoying both inequalities $0\leqslant a<(q-p)/2$ and $0\leqslant b<(q+p)/2$ we have $0<a+b+1<q$, thus it is not appropriate).
The main idea is that on $\Omega_1$ there exists a sign-reversing involution $$(a,b)\mapsto (pq-1+(q-p)/2-a,pq-1+(q+p)/2-b),$$ which preserves being an appropriate pair but changes the parity of $a+b$.
On $\Omega_2$, we must have $b=q-1-a+m\cdot q$ for $m\in \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ (since $b\equiv q-1-a\pmod q$) and $m=m(a)$ is chosen so that $q-1-2a+m(a)q$ is divisible by $p$, there exists unique such $m(a)$, and $(-1)^{a+b}=(-1)^{m(a)}$.
Analogously, on $\Omega_3$, we must have $a=q-1-b+m(b)\cdot q$, and $(-1)^{a+b}=(-1)^{m(b)}$. Thus, the sum over $\Omega_2$ and $\Omega_3$ is nothing but
$$\sum_{a=0}^{(q-p)/2-1}(-1)^{m(a)}+\sum_{b=0}^{(q+p)/2-1}(-1)^{m(b)}.$$
Now note that $m((q-1)/2)=0$ and for $0\leqslant a<q$, $a\ne (q-1)/2$, we have $m(a)+m(q-1-a)=p$. Thus, the sum of $(-1)^{m(a)}$ for $a\in [(q-p)/2,(q+p)/2-1]$ (this set is symmetric with respect to $(q-1)/2$, so we may partition it onto $\{(q-1)/2\}$ and pairs with sum $q-1$) equals $1$. Therefore,
$$
M=1+2\sum_{a=0}^{(q-p)/2-1} (-1)^{m(a)}\leqslant 1+(q-p),
$$
with equality of and only if $m(a)$ is even for all $a=0,1,\ldots,(q-p)/2-1$.

Stellar answer. And I love your way of referencing equations!

I give a way that may work for odd numbers. This is too long for a comment.
First, the quantity
$$\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)+\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big) 
= 2\cos\Big(\pi\Big(\frac{m}{p}+\frac{n}{q}\Big)\Big)
\cos\Big(\pi\Big(\frac{m}{p}-\frac{n}{q}\Big)\Big)$$
cannot vanish since $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Hence the sum is well-defined.
Call $T_p$ the Chebyshev polynomial, defined by the equality
$T_p(\cos(\theta)) = \cos(p\theta)$ for all real numbers $\theta$. Then for all integers $m$,
$$T_p\Big(\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)\Big) = T_p(\cos(2m\pi)) = T_p(\cos(0)) = 1.$$
If $p$ is odd, the real numbers $\cos(2m\pi/p)$ for $0 \le m \le (p-1)/2$ are distinct roots of $T_p$. The multiplicity is $2$ if $1 \le m \le (p-1)/2$, and $1$ if $m=0$. Therefore, we have all roots. Since $T_p$ has leading term $2^{p-1}X^p$, we derive
$$T_p - 1 = 2^{p-1}(X-1)\prod_{m=1}^{(p-1)/2}\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)\Big) = 2^{p-1} \prod_{m=1}^p\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)\Big).$$
If $q$ is odd, a similar formula holds for $q$.
Given an integer $n \in [1,q]$, one has
$$T_p\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big) - 1
= 2^{p-1} \prod_{m=1}^p\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big).$$
Thus
$$\prod_{n=1}^q\Big( T_p \Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)  - 1 \Big)
= 2^{(p-1)q} \prod_{m=1}^p \prod_{n=1}^q \Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big).$$
Call $c_{pq}X^{pq} + \cdots + c_0$ this polynomial. The sum to be estimated is the sum of the reciprocal of its roots, which is $-c_1/c_0$. So we are lead to estimate the coefficients of this polynomial...
Another strategy is to write for each integer $n \in [1,q]$,
$$\frac{T'_p\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)}{T_p\Big(X-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big) - 1}
= \sum_{m=1}^p\frac{1}{X-\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)},$$
so
$$\sum_{m=1}^p\frac{1}{\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)+\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)} = \frac{T'_p\Big(-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)}{1 - T_p\Big(-\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)} = \frac{T'_p\Big(\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)}{1 + T_p\Big(\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)\Big)},$$
since $T_p$ is an odd function.
Using the equalities $T_p(\cos(\theta)) = \cos(p\theta)$ and $-T'_p(\cos(\theta))\sin\theta = - p \sin(p\theta)$, one derives $$\sum_{m=1}^p\frac{1}{\cos\Big(\frac{2m\pi}{p}\Big)+\cos\Big(\frac{2n\pi}{q}\Big)} = p \frac{\sin(2np\pi/q)}{\sin(2n\pi/q)} \times \frac{1}{1+\cos(2np\pi/q)}.$$
It remains to sum over all integers $n \in [1,q]$ and to bound above...
